# Automatic triggering of a job

Tags: bash, batch-file

I want a batch script that will check in a share drive for a file(file name is partially fixed) and if the file exists, it will trigger a mail and also trigger an sql  job.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: And what, you want us to write this for you?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple script that tests for the file and takes the desired actions, then install a crontab with `crontab -e` to run it at any frequency you like. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test -e "/path/to/filename"; then
    echo "Hey, the file you want: filename -- exists." | \
    mail -s "file: filename exists" you@yourhost.com
    mysql -uuser -hhost -NB -e "your sql command here"
fi
```

Name it something like `filetest.sh` and make it executable `chmod 0755 filetest.sh`. Then install the crontab with `crontab -e`. Set it to run whenever you like every 10 minutes:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /path/to/filetest.sh
```

Save and you are pretty much done.